# Google Sheets: How do I delete rows with duplicate data in multiple columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Thank you all in advance for any and all help you can provide.

I am working with a spreadsheet that has peoples data(names addresses and such). I am looking for a formula that will search for duplicate last names and duplicate addresses and delete the duplicates so that only one remains.

Example:

Name-------------Address

Frank-------------123 Fake St

Bill---------------123 Fake St

Bob--------------123 Fake St

Bill---------------123 Fake St

Frank-------------123 Fake St

In this example I would want the formula to delete 1 of the Frank and 1 of the Bill entries as they both have the same name and same address.

Thank you again and I hope you have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 1):

You can used in-built function to remove duplicate value:

Suppose you want to delete those rows with duplicate value based on column A:

[image]

Highlight the region, then Goto Data > Remove Duplicates and only select column A:

[image]

Press ok and you will see the expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> In this example I would want the formula to delete 1 of the Frank and 1 of the Bill entries

use `UNIQUE`:

```
=UNIQUE(A:B)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `=concatenate()` formula to merge names addresses and addresses. Then use the in-built function to remove duplicate Menu > Data > Remove Duplicates.